# In R how to perform percentage change in time series(ts) data

Tags: r, dataframe, time-series

Suppose the dataset contains monthly data and is initiated as

```
df = ts(dfRaw[,-1], start = c(2000,1), frequency = 12)
```

But post this transformation I am unable to do operations like

```
df[, 'colname_new'] = percentageChange(df[,'colname'])

df[, 'colname_new'] = df[, 'colname1'] - df[, 'colname2']
```

Error shown is

> Error in `[<-.default`(`*tmp*`, , "Ind_trade_net", value = structure(c(-4928, : subscript out of bounds

Kindly help. New to R.

Comment: First, there is a quotation mark misssing `df[, 'colname_new'] = df[, 'colname1'] - df[, 'colname2]`

Comment: This was a typo when I was framing the question. Is there any way out? I am current transforming ts to dataframe and doing the calculations.

Comment: Could you please share some reproducible data using `dput`?

Comment: I am sorry, I know you people want to help but I am unable to upload the dataset.